# Parametrize gitlab ci pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, python

There is the following simple pipeline:
`build` → `test` → `deploy`
that uses specified `python` version for all stages, for example `3.8`.

How can I scale (parametrize) it for `python` with versions: `3.7`, `3.8` and `3.9`?
Simplest solution that comes to mind is to create 3 different pipelines with hardcoded `python` versions:
`build_37` → `test_37` → `deploy_37`
`build_38` → `test_38` → `deploy_38`
`build_39` → `test_39` → `deploy_39`.

I know this is a very bad solution.
What is the right way?

Comment: this sounds like a pretty cut-and-dry use case for [Tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) - have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use the [parallel matrix feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#fetch-artifacts-from-a-parallelmatrix-job) of GitLab CI (see also [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#parallelmatrix)). As Bruce Becker suggested utilizing `tox` is also a valid option and exactly designed for your use case.

```
build:
  image: python:${PY_VERSION}
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PY_VERSION: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9"]
  script: poetry build
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use Gitlab templates in conjunction with an environment variable that sets the python version.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize GitLab pipeline using `variables` keyword in `gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
variables:
  PYTHON_VERSION:
    value: "3.7"
    options:
      - "3.7"
      - "3.8"
      - "3.9"
    description: "Python version"
```

You can see a sample GitLab `gitlab-ci.yaml` using `variables` keyword at [my GitLab](https://gitlab.com/warrior7089/gitlab-parameterized-pipelines-demo/-/blame/main/.gitlab-ci.yml#L10) or read an article about [GitLab Parameterized Pipelines](https://rokpoto.com/gitlab-parameterized-pipelines/).

Disclaimer: I wrote the above article.